# Java: Parsing Json Correctly?

Tags: java, php, json

I have an array in Json that output:

```
print json_decode($array);
```

The string results in:

```
{"dbonline":true,"success":true,"action":"geturls","authorized":true,
 "urls":[
     {"url":"http:\/\/www.namhost.com"},
     {"url":"http:\/\/www.voomka.com"},
     {"url":"http:\/\/www.ournamibia.com"}]
}
```

Note the // part. That is how i get it back from this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

I then use Java to grab the URL where this is printed, and then I parse it:

```
private ArrayList<String> extractUrls(String jsonText)
{
    ArrayList<String> urlResults = new ArrayList<String>();
    JsonParserFactory factory    = JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
    JSONParser parser            = factory.newJsonParser();
    Map jsonData                 = parser.parseJson(jsonText);
    ArrayList urlList            = (ArrayList)jsonData.get("urls");
    for (Object u : urlList)
    {
        HashMap hashmap = (HashMap)u;
        String url = hashmap.get("url").toString();
        urlResults.add(url);
    }
    return urlResults;
}
```

The problem is, the array list being return has values:

```
[0] = (String) "http:\\/\\/www.namhost.com\\/blog\\/2014-06-11\\/how-to-choose-right-software-solution"
```

In other words, the json "slashing" hasn't been removed. I don't want to manually remove it here, as it seems the problem is probably with the parsing directly.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: add `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` as the 2nd argument

Comment: echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); says --> Use of undefined constant JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES - assumed 'JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES' in

Comment: Ahh...not available, looks like you're going to need to do it manually then.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code: There is no need of escape sequence

```
 {"dbonline":true,"success":true,"action":"geturls","authorized":true,
     "urls":[
        {"url":"http://www.namhost.com"},
             {"url":"http://www.voomka.com"},
             {"url":"http://www.ournamibia.com"}]
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that it comes back escaped from the PHP script?

Comment: I made an update to the code to show how PHP spits it back. Is it maybe a PHP problem.

Comment: That would work yes. My question is ... do I: a) change php to so it spits out the json without the escapes, or b) get java to take out the slashes. In both cases, how? This is not working for me --> echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

Comment: use java to tack out the slashes

Comment: use   "http:\\/\\/www.namhost.com\\/blog\\/2014-06-11\\/how-to-choose-right-software-solution".replace("/","");